# Pgfplots produces errorbars with shifted end lines

Tags: tikz

I have a problem regarding the error bars in pgfplots. The example provided produces error bars but the horizontal lines at the end are shifted and not aligned with the vertical line. I tried different online-examples but I was not able to resolve the problem. Unfortunately, I can not post the output. Thanks for your help!

```
\addplot [
color=black,
only marks,
mark=diamond*,
mark options={solid},
]
plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]
table[row sep=crcr,x index={0},y index={1}, y error index={2} ]{
0 0 1\\
};
```

Comment: \documentclass[multi=false,tikz=true,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [
color=black,
only marks,
mark=diamond*,
mark options={solid},
]
plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]
table[row sep=crcr,x index={0},y index={1}, y error index={2} ]{
0 0 1\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

compiles properly on my system (I've copied and pasted your exact code into axis environment)